# How to summarise pattern in binomial-type expansion into a single expression

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I have a series of polynomials as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
&1\\
&1+4x^3+x^6\\
&1+20x^3+48x^6+20x^9+x^{12}\\
&1+54x^3+405x^6+760x^9+405x^{12}+54x^{15}+ x.^{18}\\
& \vdots\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

and I want to find a general expression that will generate these.

I have noted that the coefficients follow a recognised (and documented) pattern:

```
1;
1, 4, 1;
1, 20, 48, 20, 1;
1, 54, 405, 760, 405, 54, 1;
1, 112, 1828, 8464, 13840, 8464, 1828, 112, 1;
1, 200, 5925, 52800, 182700, 273504, 182700, 52800, 5925, 200, 1;
1, 324, 15606, 233300, 1424925, 4050864, 5703096, 4050864, 1424925, 233300, 15606, 324, 1; ...
```

My initial researches have identified that the coefficients of my polynomials are those listed in the first set of numbers (above),which is the known integer sequence A181544 as listed at https://oeis.org/A181544.

The listing goes on to give the generating function for the polynomial coefficients:

```
Row generating functions begin:
(1) = (1-x)*(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +...);
(1 + 4*x + x^2) = (1-x)^4*(1 + 2^3*x + 3^3*x^2 + 4^3*x^3 +...);
(1 + 20*x + 48*x^2 + 20*x^3 + x^4) = (1-x)^7*(1 + 3^3*x + 6^3*x^2 +...);
(1 + 54*x + 405*x^2 + 760*x^3 + 405*x^4 + 54*x^5 + x^6) = (1-x)^10*(1 + 4^3*x + 10^3*x^2 + 20^3*x^3 + 35^3*x^4 +...); ...
```

and provides a combinatorial formulae for doing so.  For row $n$ the $k^{th}$ term where $0<k<2n$ is:

\begin{equation}
\left\{\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{n+k-1}{k}^3 x^{k}\right\} \left(1-x\right)^{3n+1}
\end{equation}

I have two problems:  (1) I am unable to generate the given example polynomials from this expression - how is that done ? and (2) my polynomials are in powers of $x^3$, (see (1) above). How do I modify this algorithm to generate these?

Answer (score 2):

The expression given in the OEIS header seems to have a mismatch between the $n$ in the binomial coefficient and the $n$ in the exponent on $1-x$. If you change the displayed formula to

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}k^3x^k\right)(1-x)^{3n-2}\,,$$

it will give you the correct results for row $n$. For instance, for row $2$ you get

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+1}k^3x^k\right)(1-x)^4=(1-x)^4\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)^3x^k\,,$$

exactly as in the second line in the table of row generating functions. If you number the rows starting with $0$ instead of $1$, it becomes

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n+k}k^3x^k\right)(1-x)^{3n+1}\,;$$

it appears that they inadvertently mixed the expressions for the two origins.

It seems to me that the simplest way to generate your polynomials is to generate these and then multiply every exponent on $x$ by $3$.